# Remove a skype account via AccountManager.removeAccount() in Android

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm trying to play a bit with Accounts via `AccountManager` on my Android Phone and would like to write an app to remove some accounts. My code works on facebook accounts but fails on skype account .

Any clues on how to remove these kind of accounts (except of course opening the xml and remove the desired line)

```
result=accountManager.removeAccount(Account, null, null); 

remove_result=result.getResult(); //-> true for a facebook account , false for a skype account .
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be forbidden from removing some accounts if they are needed for something else (like Android Market, etc.). IIRC, the code that does this check is system-level, so you can't change it. Don't know why it forbids you from deleting Skype accounts though. Check logcat output, might be some hints there.

Comment: Thanks already for your quick answer. I'll try the hard way then .
Editing the accounts.xml file should do the trick. The only remaining question is about rights. Do you think being super user will be sufficient ?
TIA
Christophe.

Comment: Editing accounts.xml might break things, so do take backups. Yes, if you have root access you can do anything :) If you are trying to do this programmatically though, it might be a bit tricky. You'll have to copy the file, edit and copy back. Or come up with a shell command(s) that can edit it in place.

Comment: Don't where you got the `super()` from, but you need to start a new process, execute su in the shell, and execute command you want to run with with root privileges in that process. You can't just get root privileges in your activity or service.