# Facebook android application logout

Tags: android, facebook

I  would like to add functionality to my application that lets me log out of the facebook android app.

Is there a way to do it without having to register my app with facebook as I do not need any other facebook functions except log out.

Does anyone know of any starting points?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your app can penetrate into other running app's functionality, unless the Facebook app itself has provided any interface for this.

Comment: I see.
What about ending the session by deleting just the account data.

Comment: but then the question is, **can you delete other app's credentials in Accounts?** still, i dont think it is possible, otherwise its a security issue. [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10781907/966550)